# Session expire only on logout

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working in a cakephp project. I want to keep login session value as long as user click on logout button. How it is possible.
thanks in advance

Comment: Go through the documentation. Check the `Auth` component.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set `session` time out in the **app/Config/core.php**.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
                'timeout' => 200000,//minutes
                'autoRegenerate' => false,//not resets session on activity
                'cookieTimeout' => 144000000
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie expire `0`, then the cookie never expire until you clear it.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
```